# My API on railway is only in "building" state, logs don't show any errors

Tags: node.js, api, deployment, railway

So I put my API node on the railway and it stayed in the "building" state. I set the build command to "npm start" and the root directory to "api". I've been trying to solve this for a few hours and I don't know why it doesn't say "success". I've seen countless tutorials on youtube and followed them, but it didn't work.

Code in the log:

```
#13 2.374
#13 2.375 Sequelize CLI [Node: 16.18.1, CLI: 6.6.0, ORM: 6.28.0]
#13 2.375
#13 2.424 Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
#13 2.424 Using environment "production". 
#13 2.603 No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date. 
#13 3.024 Server is on in 3000
#13 ...
#5 [stage-0  2/10] WORKDIR /app/
#5 sha256:8a2728349c4dca0cbfe99c7a43344101bf52e7b3fd086e87a928a471b6406ab9
#5 CACHED
#13 [stage-0  9/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/105c689f-b12b-4cf9-85c6-377e0dba556b-node_modules/cache,target=/app/node_modules/.cache npm run start
#13 sha256:1d70f3d431ad78443471920f385859b9d2f9337ba397193b22c696580d31fa8d`
```

This is what appears in the log